# Why simple redirection does not work in Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, redirect, command-line, cmd

I want output of any command not just to show on console, but also to file. I have used simple command,

```
dir > out.txt 1>&2
```

Now what I am assuming here in command is, output of dir will go to out.txt, and *1* which is *stdout* will be redirected to *2* which is *stderr*.

My problem is that the output is being shown in the console but not being written to out.txt

Now console will show both stdout and stderr, so I am using stderr to show my output on console.

Please consider, their may be any other way to do the same thing. But I wanted to know what is problem with my logic.

Comment: What is your error? Does it work?  Does it do what you expect? What doe s it do instead?

Comment: It shows output on console but output not getting added to out.txt

Comment: Not sure. Will they not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each stream has only one target. In your code

```
dir > out.txt 1>&2
```

you are requesting that the target for data sent by `dir` to stdout will be a file, and just after it, you change again the target for stdout stream, assigning it to a duplicate of the target in stderr stream.

There is no way to do it with only redirection operators. You will need some kind of `tee` utility. There is a good collection of answers here at SO giving you solutions coded in several lenguages.